# TextView not moving up with keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessageController in my chat application. In that view controller i have added one more text view at the top to add recipients. JSQMessage chat bar goes up if the focus is on JSQMessage chat bar, it doesn't goes up if the focus is on other text field. How i can forcefully move that bar up ?

See Image for further clarification. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: you should post some code

Comment: Exactly what code you want me to post?

Comment: you just post image. people is not getting better understanding to help you

Comment: what does the `JSQMessageController` documentation say about the issue (beyond the actual _JSQMessageController_ all deprecated and not maintained any longer)?

Comment: Why do you want to move the JSQMessage chat bar up when editing the recipients field?

Comment: I'm unsure where this will work with the Pods you are using or with your code - however have you looked at IQKeyboardManager?

Comment: @holex, I didn't find anything relevant to this issue.